# Horror film involving the ghost of a bullied student killing off his tormentors, with the climax involving destroying his asthma inhaler

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, ghost

I think I ran into this one in 2020-2021 while searching for a different film. The setup was a fairly typical one of a set of students (high school age, I think?) are being killed off one-by-one with them all being tied together by having bullied (or not interfered in the bullying of) a student with asthma, resulting in his death, maybe when his inhaler is kept from him when he needs it. He comes back as a ghost or other kind of revenant and starts enacting revenge. Somewhere near the end of the film, the protagonists manage to stop the killer by crushing the inhaler (I don't know if the killer was carrying it, or if they found it and broke it symbolically. Either way, it either weakened or banished the ghost). Unfortunately, one of them was carrying an inhaler (whether it was their own, the original that was grabbed from the dead student, or another they'd taken from him earlier) and the ghost got ahold of it and started killing again.

Since I didn't actually watch the movie (just read the summary), that's about all of the details I remember. I think that the victims were all jocks and/or "popular kids" and their hangers on. I was initially thinking it was an Asian horror movie, but the more I think about it, the more my brain is going to the film being set in the United States or England.

And... that led to me using the right search terms to find the film.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The film I was thinking of is the 2009 British horror film, *[Tormented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tormented_(2009_British_film))*.

> Head girl Justine Fielding (Tuppence Middleton) is escorted out of Fairview High School by the police, as other pupils look on.
>
> Five days earlier, Justine is reading the eulogy at the funeral of unpopular, asthmatic student Darren Mullet (Calvin Dean). Mullet's equally unpopular friend, Jason Banks (Olly Alexander), is (literally) thrown out of the church by the sadistic P.E. teacher after calling her a hypocrite because she did not really know him. Later, Justine agrees to go to a party with Alex (Dimitri Leonidas), organised by his popular friends, Bradley (Alex Pettyfer), Tasha (April Pearson), Khalillah (Larissa Wilson), Sophie (Georgia King) and Marcus (Tom Hopper).
>
> When Justine arrives at the party, the DJ Jez (Ben Lloyd-Hughes), egged on by Tasha, raps unflatteringly about her, before being thrown out of the party by Bradley. Bradley, Tasha, Khalillah, Marcus and Sophie all receive insulting text messages from Mullet's number. Later, Alex and Justine go to a bedroom and make out, only to be pranked by Bradley, wearing a clown costume and pretending to attack them with a chainsaw. Later, the 'in-crowd' toast Mullet. Justine admits that she didn't know who he was. Jez goes to the cemetery and urinates on Mullet's grave. He is stabbed with a wooden crucifix by Mullet's ghost.

....

> Justine stops [Mullet], but he begins to choke her to death. She takes Mullet's inhaler and throws it across the room, telling Alex to break it. He does, and the ghost begins to die. Justine tells Alex to leave, but he finds Mullet's other inhaler, which Alex had hidden from Mullet when he was alive. Mullet then uses it, restoring his strength, and stabs Alex in the throat with the screwdriver before disappearing....

It sounds like Mullet committed suicide rather than his death being the direct result of the bullying, but otherwise it matches.

Eventually found with the straightforward terms of `horror film students bullying inhaler`. Previously, I was fixated on the idea of it being an Asian film, and had appropriate search terms in there.